# character array initialisation

Tags: c, string

Look at Following code fragment

```
char ch[10] = "hello"; // is ok
```

but

```
char ch[10];
ch = "hello"; // showing lvalue error
```

It should have to be possible according to the concept that array decays into pointer.Why here ch is not decaying to char *?
please describe the  distinction between the two.

Comment: do you know what is `lvalue`?

Comment: Yes.these are those which takes space in memory and may be assignable or not

Comment: yes, lvalues are assignable values. In your case ch points to the address of first element of itself i.e. to its base address. So you can not change the base address of an array, whereas you can change the value at base address of array. Hence in this case `ch` is not a `lvalue`. See my answer for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

case 1 :-

`char ch[10] = "hello";`

Take the base address to be 1000

By your declaration

> 1000 -> h
>   1001 -> e
>   1002 -> l
>   1003 -> l
>   1004 -> o
>   1005 -> \0

And ch is pointing to `1000`.

case 2:-

`char ch[10];

 ch="hello";`

> 1000 -> garbage
>   1001 -> garbage
>   1002 -> garbage
>   1003 -> garbage
>   1004 -> garbage
>   1005 -> garbage
>   and so on

Note that `hello` is a independent string having its own address, so by `ch="hello"`

You are trying `ch` to point to the new address of `h` in `"hello"`.

Which is impossible as `ch` is of type `char *const`.

I mean to say that `ch` will always point to its base address and you can not change the base address of an array.

You can change the values of an array, but not the addresses of array elements.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not assignable.  If you need to allocate  a string dynamically then you either A) create a fixed length buffer beforehand and populate it, or B) allocate the memory dynamically and, again, populate it.

It all depends on whether or not you know the size beforehand (though C does support variable length arrays, but be careful) or if you need to accommodate a string of arbitrary length.

To copy a string into an existing buffer (allocated with automatic storage duration or otherwise) you can use `strcpy`, `strncpy` (for inserting into existing strings), `strdup` (POSIX), read it in with `fgets`, or whatever other method is appropriate.  Be careful of buffer sizes and string lengths.

Answer (score 2):

```
char ch[10] = "hello";
```

is initialisation, and is allowed by the standard. It's effectively "give me a ten-char array and populate it with the C string `"hello"`.

```
char ch[10];
ch = "hello";
```

is (attempted) assignment, and is not permitted. You can do:

```
char *ch;
ch = "hello";
```

but then you end up with a `ch` that you're not allowed to modify (it's undefined behaviour as to whether or not you're allowed to modify string constants).

One way to get "assignment" happening with the array *after* initialisation time is:

```
char ch[10];
strcpy (ch, "hello");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should understand the difference between initialization and assignment. Initialization is defining a variable and assigning it a value in the same statement. The following statement defines a variable `ch` of type `char[10]` - an array of `10` characters and then assigns it with a string literal.

```
char ch[10] = "hello";
```

This is equivalent to

```
char ch[10] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

Note that you assign only the first `6` elements of the array `ch`, the remaining `4` are implicitly initialized to the null character - `'\0'`. Therefore, the above two statements do the same as:

```
char ch[10] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'};
```

An assignment is when you first define a variable and then assign it a value in a separate statement.

```
char ch[10];  // define ch of type char[10]. contains garbage right now.
```

You should not use `ch` just after defining it because it contains garbage value. Next, you should assign it a value but then you can't assign it like you did in initialization. That's not allowed by the rules of `C`. You can't assign all elements of the array in one go but must assign each element of the array separately.

```
char ch[10];
const char *s = "hello";
int len = strlen(s);
for(int i = 0; i <= len; i++)    // copy the null byte as well
    ch[i] = s[i];
```

Here, you have assigned only the first `6` elements of the array `ch`, the remaining `4` still contain garbage values unless you assign them. That's one difference here between array initialization and assignment.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
char ch[10];
ch = "hello";
```

is not valid in C. After you declared your array, you cant reassign it. The name of an array is actually the address of the first element of that array. `ch` is an array, `hello` is also array, it does not have name but it has it's own address, so this `ch = "hello";` line, is an attempt to reassign `ch` with another address, which is not valid. 
You can only

```
strcpy(ch,"hello");
```

in order to put `hello` into it

Answer (score 0):

ch = "hello" is not initialization, it's assignment. Also `"hello"` type and `ch` type is different.

Change it to `char ch[10] ="hello"`.